# Locally cached dns cannot be uncached through cache refresh linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, ip

So I run a semi-private website for myself, locally hosted on my network, and port forwarded to the web. I changed from using one computer to another to host it, and whilst my public IP address correctly points to the new computer, the subdomain I'm using to access it doesn't.

From what I've gathered so far, this is only an issue on the old host computer, when I dig the subdomain, I get a reply from that localhost saying the subdomain points to localhost, but everywhere else the new subdomain points to the public IP. If I dig and ask even my router for the correct IP it points to the public one.

I've tried to flush the dns cache, but that didnt change anything.

I'm running Ubuntu Linux, and really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it was set in my /etc/hosts file, I must've done that and forgotten about it